# Circularly polarized light and polarizing filter

Tags: visible-light, polarization

Does circularly polarized light pass through a linear polarizing filter, regardless of the orientation of such filter?

Comment: Might be worth the experiment ;)

Comment: Yes, I thought so too. I already bought the filters and then I didn't know where to get the circular polarized light source.

Comment: @ChrisV 3D Glasses! Well, the right kind fo 3D gogggles work as circular polarizers.

Comment: @Thriveth Good point. Thanks. What I've noticed, though is that the glasses seem to be working as a circular filter on one (front) side and linear on the other side. Could this be the case?

Comment: @ChrisV As far as I understand, a circular polarizer is basically a linear polarizer with a quarter-wave plate slapped onto it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can pass, and will have the linear polarization of the filter.
However, what they do in 3D movie goggles is to put in front of the linear polarizer a quarter wave filter. This polarizes the light in a specific direction, perpendicular relative to each eye.

This ensures that the circularly polarized light of each image passes only to one eye. Otherwise you will see a double image, because each linear polarizer will let light pass from both images (although with a different polarization) so it will be visible and you will no longer perceive a 3D image

Comment: Too bad. If it had kept the circular polarization, I would've had an idea for an application